# css attributes all blank javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attributes

I am using jQuery to edit html elements using .each on all off a class. If I try to log any of the attributes then I will just get "" even though I have set the attributes to something in my css file.

Why is this happening? Can the javascript file not access the css attributes?

Comment: Post sample code

Comment: `.css` can only access the attributes that are in the `style="..."` attribute, or were added by `.css()` dynamically. It doesn't return attributes that are inherited from style sheets.

Comment: To get inherited attributes, you have to use the native Javascript `getComputedStyle` function.

Comment: Getting computed elements is not so simple. See the question I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm unclear whether you mean CSS attributes or DOM element attributes, here's an explanation for both:

To loop through some elements before reading their (in this case `value`) attributes, you can do this like:

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('value') );
});
```

To loop through some elements before reading their CSS properties, you can do this like:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).css('width') );
});
```

Take a look at the console to see the three elements width being output: https://jsfiddle.net/nrfxn9nb/